# http_build_query param for ?

Tags: php, get

Does anyone know how to make `http_build_query` add a `?` at the beginning if one is not present?

Right now I am adding  index.php? to all of my links. I have reasons to NOT want the ? hardcoded into the link. If http_build_query would just add it if one isn't present some how, that would be a huge help.

Comment: Write a short functions that does it.

Answer (score 1):

`http_build_query()` doesn't parse URLs, so it can't know where you're appending the string it returns. You could append the `?` to URL if it doesn't already have one, then append the result of `http_build_query()` to that.

Example:

```
$params = http_build_query(...);
if (strrpos($url, '?') !== strlen($url) - 1) {
    // if the value in $url does not end with a ?, append one
    $url .= '?';
}
$url .= $params;
```

Comment: I need to somehow do a IF ? exists http_build_query(), if not prepend ?.  Help? :)

Comment: @user1837671, example added.

Answer (score 0):

if `$url` holds the part where you want to append your query string and `$q` is the result of the `http_build_query` then a one liner would be:

```
$url2 = strpos($url, '?')?$url.'&'.$q:$url.'?'.$q;
```

The assumption of course for that general case is that $url is valid and the existing query string URL-encoded.

some test code:

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
$params = array('q'=>'something', 'q2'=>'something else');
$q = http_build_query($params);
$url2 = strpos($url, '?')?$url.'&'.$q:$url.'?'.$q;
echo 'Original url: ', $url, PHP_EOL, 'Final url: ', $url2, PHP_EOL;
$url = 'http://google.com/?extra=som';
$url2 = strpos($url, '?')?$url.'&'.$q:$url.'?'.$q;
echo 'Original url: ', $url, PHP_EOL, 'Final url: ', $url2, PHP_EOL;
```

and the output:

```
Original url: http://google.com
Final url: http://google.com?q=something&q2=something+else
Original url: http://google.com/?extra=som
Final url: http://google.com/?extra=som&q=something&q2=something+else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$parse_url = parse_url($url);
$url2 = $parse_url['scheme'] . '://' . $parse_url['host'] . $parse_url['path'] . '?' . ($parse_url['query'] ? $parse_url['query'] . '&' : '') . http_build_query($params);

?>
```